# when use "heroku run rails test ", I got error "add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile" , and it's already added to my gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile

I'm creating a new rails application, and I'm working on the registration system, based on "rails tutorial" book, but I got a problem, when I run

```
rails test
```

on my local machine for my rails app, I got no errors

but when push the app to heroku, and then run

```
heroku run rails test
```

I got this error

```
 Error:
    UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information:
    NoMethodError: assert_template has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it,
            add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile.
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

this is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.5.1"

gem 'rails',        '5.1.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.12'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.11.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.10.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

any solutions please, knowing that I'm still newbie :)

Comment: `heroku` probably does not install the test or development group, as it typically should not.

Comment: What @jordanm said. Heroku is not running under the test environment and thus it does not bundle in the test gems.